# Does the first asterick in pointcut expression stand for "any return type" or "any access modifier"?

Tags: spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

Please consider this pointcut expression:

```
@Before("execution(* org.mycompany.service.*.get*())")
```

I understand that an advice annotated by the expression above will execute for all methods who belong to a class in the package `org.mycompany.service` and whose names start with "get". My question is: what does the first asterick stand for? Is it a wildcard for access modifier or for return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-examples)

The format of an execution expression follows:

```
execution(modifiers-pattern? ret-type-pattern declaring-type-pattern?name-pattern(param-pattern) throws-pattern?)
```

> All parts except the returning type pattern (ret-type-pattern in the
> preceding snippet), the name pattern, and the parameters pattern are
> optional

So in the given code , first * represents ret-type-pattern